# Submit function jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two trigger click function in my form one is a link and the other one is a submit button.

The link trigger `('.quiz-progress')` is working well to submit form with id `$("#quiz-question-answering-form")` of form, but the button `('#edit-navigation-back')` is not. It cannot submit `$("#quiz-question-answering-form").submit();`

It makes me confuse because when I change the submit function in the button to alert method is working.

so what i need is when user click radio box the button automatically submit it..?

Here's the full code

```
//fist trigger link <a href="#" class="quiz-progress">link</a> ( working well)
$(".query-once-1-processed").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        //do something it does have the protected class!
        $("#edit-navigation-skip").hide();
        $('#edit-navigation-submit').show();
        $(".quiz-progress").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
            $("#quiz-question-answering-form").submit();
        });
    } else{
        $('#edit-navigation-submit').hide();
    }
}); 

//second trigger (button) cannot submit the form (not working)
$(".multichoice-row").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        $("#edit-navigation-back").click(function() {
            //e.preventDefault(); // if desired...      
            $("#quiz-question-answering-form").submit();
            //alert ("ok");
        });
    }
});
```

here is the html markup

```
<form class="answering-form" action="/learning/node/27/take/2" method="post" id="quiz-question-answering-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <table>
   <tbody>
     <tr class="multichoice-row query-once-processed-1"><td width="35"><div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-question-1-answer-user-answer">
       <input type="radio" id="edit-question-1-answer-user-answer-142" name="question1" value="142" class="form-radio" /> 
       </div>
    </td><td><p>Hulk</p>
     </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
     <input type="submit" id="edit-navigation-back" name="op" value="&lt; Soal Sebelumnya" class="form-submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the markup...

Comment: Just to be clear, you're attaching a new click event to `$("#edit-navigation-back)` every time you click a row...? If you click the row 10 times and then click the `edit-navigation-back` button, it's going to fire the event 10 times. As an example, [check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/vp8b03f1/) - Click the outer button 10 times, and then click the inner button, and check console. While this isn't the root of your issue, it's definitely something to be wary of.

Comment: you need to show the HTML, otherwise it's not really clear how this all fits together. Santi's comment is very valid though, this is a bad way to assign click handlers. Also, what does "not working" mean? That doesn't describe the problem at all. Does nothing happen? Does something unexpected happen? is there an error in your browser console? Please try and be specific and detailed.

Comment: i have showed the html mark up, please help, thanks !

Comment: since the "edit-navigation-back" button is already a "submit" button, then `$("#edit-navigation-back").click(function() {
            //e.preventDefault(); // if desired...      
            $("#quiz-question-answering-form").submit();
            //alert ("ok");
        });` will have no effect unless you include the "e.preventDefault()". A standard postback will have happened automatically before this is executed (or at least. simultaneously).